# Open File from PowerShell via c#

Tags: c#, powershell

In PowerShell this command: `Invoke-Item D:\myFile.txt` will open the file named `myFile`.

I'm tryind to run this **PowerShell command From C#**

I tried:

## NuGet: `System.Management.Automation`

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {
               
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Invoke-Item D:\tx.txt");
                PowerShellInstance.Invoke();              
            }
```

But this not opens the file

Comment: `"Invoke-Item D:\tx.txt"` -> `"Invoke-Item D:\\tx.txt"`

Comment: Dammm that's the answer @PetSerAl

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
 Process process = new Process();
 string scriptPath = $"YourPowershellCommand.ps1";
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
 {
     FileName = scriptPath,
     RedirectStandardError = true;
     RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     CreateNoWindow = true;
     UseShellExecute = false
  };
  process.StartInfo = startInfo;
  process.Start();
  var stderrx = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
  var stdout = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

  process.WaitForExit();
```

Just save your powershell command in a ps1 file and give the path as a parameter. The code is not tested but it should work. Also C# process is in System.Diagnostics namespace.

Comment: You can not read from `StandardError`, if you did not redirect it. You can not redirect streams, if you use `UseShellExecute = true`. Also default shell action is to open script in `notepad`, but not to execute it.